# on scroll "sticky-element" will need stick to before "footer-area" not on bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one "sticky-element" div, on page load which I have been set position:fixed with bottom right aligned.

**Requirement** : on page scroll I would like to set it stick to just before on my "footer-area".

**Issue** : I have handled successfully css and js part on load, but I am not able to find logic that how can i add another class to my "sticky-element" once "footer-area" will start visible on window.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="page-section">
    <p>lots of code and other div nested in this as well</p>
</div>
<div class="sticky-element">
</div>
<div class="footer-area">
</div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(){
        $(".sticky-element").addClass("some-class");
    }

    else {
        $(".sticky-element").removeClass("some-class");
    }
});
```

});

**css**

```
.sticky-element { position:fixed; }
```

.sticky-element.some-class { position:static; }

In above one **if()** my logic is that I would like to use if "footer-area" is visible on window than only add class will works.

Please suggest if anyone has Simple and short(not too much complex) coding way for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
     <div class="container">
         <div id='wraper'>
            <div class="page-section">
              <p>lots of code and other div nested in this as well</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sticky-element">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="footer-area">
         </div>
     </div>


   $(window).on("load",function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {    

        var bottomOfWraper = $('#wraper').offset().top + $('#wraper').outerHeight();
        var bottomOfWin = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottomOfWin > bottomOfWraper){
            $(".sticky-element").addClass("some-class");
        }

        else {
            $(".sticky-element").removeClass("some-class");
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomas for such a beautiful and clear solution, Nice logic you have been used, I have try this and only issue I am find here is page will flicker once i reached to my footer area. I will try to fix it from my end to resolve it, rest logic is working fine.

In case you need to check css for this, I have been updated in my question css part as well.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what your problem is.